# DISTINCTで複数カラム

Tags: mysql, sql

ふたつのカラムを重複しないように取得したたいです。

SELECT DISTINCT color FROM dog
blue
red
yellow
black

SELECT DISTINCT age FROM dog
4
3
8
5

SELECT文一回でこのようにしたいです。
blue
red
yellow
black
4
3
8
5

ちなみにこれではありません。
SELECT DISTINCT age,color FROM dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM dog
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT age FROM dog
```

でしょうか？
見たところカラムのデータ型が異なるようで、その点についてどのような結果を求めているのか言及されていませんでした。また、カラム単体でなく２つのカラム間での重複についてどのような結果を求めているか言及されていませんでしたので、ひとまず重複させる回答としました。カラム間についても重複排除する場合は`UNION ALL`の代わりに`UNION`を使用します。

Comment: 型はいずれもテキストで関係ありません。
UNIONで思い通り行きました。助かりました